# Word VBA: Save as Picture

Tags: vba, ms-word

Does anyone know if it's possible to run the Word "Save as Picture" dialog from VBA?
Note:
I've searched high and low to no avail, suggesting it just may not be possible.
Still, thought it worth at least asking.

To clarify (as requested): This question is simply as asked.
At the time of asking, I could not find an answer to that anywhere. At the time of this editing, this is the only place I know of that answers this question (i.e. the basic question of can this be done, and if so how?).
As it turns out, yes it can be done (see below for how). And, while there may be other ways to do something similar by evoking architecturally different approaches (which I had already seen at the time of asking), they don't answer the question as asked.
Now, I can't see what's unclear about that or why it needs or more details.
So now I ask: Is there something fundamentally wrong with asking a question like this here on SO?

Comment: Not sure why ppl have marked down this question. Note that I spent a lot of time researching this. Searched Microsoft, here, etc., etc., and read anything related. I have literally exhausted all research efforts. Marking down indicates 'lacks research or is unclear'. Perhaps that chose to mark it down, can elucidate what more I should have done?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65060336/extracting-images-from-word-document-using-vba) help?

Comment: @Raymond Wu. Thanks, but doesn't fit the workflow in this case. My answer below does what I need to do. I did edit the post above here to say that (to save others spending time on this, as I can't mark the answer yet). But Ken White deleted that edit for some reason.

Comment: I'm aware that you have an answer and I believe your edit is not necessary as it does not matter who answers it. Nevertheless I just want to highlight to you that there are other solutions to what you want to achieve which we do not know whether it fits your workflow simply because you did not specify so in your research effort/question.

Comment: @Raymond Wu: All good. Did say thanks and meant it. I do understand there's many ways to skin a cat and didn't get into the workflow details because it wasn't relevant to the core question I posed. Was simply trying to figure out "can this (as expressed) be done?" At the time I posed it, I hadn't found a way, and hadn't found [anywhere] a "yes or no" on it. Have since worked out it's a yes and how. So there's that (for what it's worth). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the solution was there, just hard to find. While the control isn’t on the ribbon, it still exists in the CommandBars.  I managed to expose that by dumping out a list of all CommandBar controls (to find it and get the id). So, the solution is:

```
''' Note: Picture must be selected first
CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=5736).Execute
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerPoint to export the graphic. Here's a macro from a recent project that exports a map of the world. The Word graphics are EMF files:

```
Public Sub ExportMap()
Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim pptSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim pptShapeRange As PowerPoint.ShapeRange
Dim Path$, File$
Dim oRange As Range

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  myDate$ = Format(Date, "m-d-yyyy")
  Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
  Path$ = ActiveDocument.Path & Application.PathSeparator
  File$ = "WorldMap " & myDate$ & ".png"
  Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Add(msoFalse)
  
  Set oRange = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("WholeMap").Range
  oRange.CopyAsPicture
  
  Set pptSlide = pptPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutBlank)
  On Error Resume Next
  With pptPres.PageSetup
    .SlideSize = 7
    .SlideWidth = 1150
    .SlideHeight = 590
  End With
  Set pptShapeRange = pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile, Link:=msoFalse)
  
  pptSlide.Export Path$ & File$, "PNG"
  
  pptApp.Quit
  
  Set pptPres = Nothing
  Set pptApp = Nothing
  Set pptSlide = Nothing
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  MsgBox "All done! Check the folder containing this template for a file called '" & File$ & "'."
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I saw the above somewhere when I was researching. Also found a possible solution using excel (via excel charts). My question though is "can one run the word 'save as picture' in word vba?" Given your response, are you saying "no that's not possible?'